# Get all the keys from TinyDB database

Tags: python, tinydb

I create a tinydb database that looks as such:

```
{"_default": 
    {"1": {"word": "cat", "definition": "Its an animal."}, 
     "2": {"word": "cat", "definition": "Its an animal."}, 
     "3": {"word": "man", "definition": "has a hand"}, 
     "4": {"word": "girl", "definition": "Its a kid"}, 
     "5": {"word": "superman", "definition": "A hero."}
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve every value for the field "word". How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may retrieve all rows, then parse to get the different `word` field in a `set` for example

```
all_rows = db.all()

all_words = {row['word'] for row in all_rows}     # set comprehension
all_words = set(map(lambda x: x['home'], values)) # map operation
```